# How to target classes with queryselector when using react-css-modules

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-css-modules

React-css-modules makes up class names on the fly to limit name clashes while using standalone components. Thats awesome. But once the DOM is loaded and you need to target a class for an animation, for instance, the class names that css-modules comes up with are, in parts, randomized.

How to go about with this?

Answer (score 2):

According from [react-css-modules official doc](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#loops-and-child-components), you can target class like bellow

```js
render() {
    const animated = this.props.styles['animated']
    return <div className={animated}>something</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Query selector shouldn't be necessary with react just attach a ref to the element you want and you have access to it within any function of the react component. 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up using the [classNames npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)
to add and remove classes to an element when I need more than one. Works like this:

```
let myClasses = classNames({
  'button': true,
  'special': this.state.special
})

<button className={myClasses} />
```